# Asking for input thrice, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name;
    int age;

    Console.WriteLine("How old are you?");

    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(input, out age))
    {
        {
            agedetermine();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give me an actual answer...");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
            Console.WriteLine("I don't have all day.");
        while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
        {
            agedetermine();
        }
    }

}
```

**agedetermine()** only contains **if** and **Console.WriteLine** nothing relevant

For the first **input = Console.ReadLine** I deliberately entered non-integers to trigger the **else**, but after that I have to enter the integer three times for the program to respond. Can someone tell me why and also give me a proper coding?
I just started out yesterday so I don't know anything, so please explain the function of any new terms you introduce into my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your last `while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))` is missing a `!`.

Now it loops until you entered something bad, instead of the other way around.

This should be the last `while` (although it is useless):

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
```

A small suggestion to prevent code repetition: use a `do...while`:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("How old are you?");
}
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age));

agedetermine();
```

Or even expanded with the message:

```
int age;

string[] messages = new string[] { "How old are you?"
                                 , "Give me an actual answer..."
                                 , "I don't have all day."
                                 };
int numberOfTries = 0;
do
{
    if (numberOfTries >= messages.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(messages[messages.Length - 1]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(messages[numberOfTries]);
    }

    numberOfTries++;
}
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age));

agedetermine();
```

Comment: Yes that was very helpful I appreciate it! I got a few more questions from your response ._. 1. What does the plus signs in numberOfTries++; do? 2. What does .Length mean? does it involve making a string (when added .Length) into an integer? 3. Does string [] mean having more than 1 data stored? thanks :)

Comment: 1. It is short for `numberOfTries = numberOfTries + 1;`. 2. The length of the array. 3. That is the definition of an array. Usually you put a number to tell the length of the array but since I instantiate it immediately I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Your last if statement is missing the NOT part

```
while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
```

should be

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify your code you don't need the last `while` loop at all.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name;
    int age;

    Console.WriteLine("How old are you?");

    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    {
        if (int.TryParse(input, out age))
        {
            {
                agedetermine();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Give me an actual answer...");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
                Console.WriteLine("I don't have all day.");
            agedetermine();

        }
    }
}
```